# Solving ordinary second-order differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE:

$$ \ddot{z} + \big( 3 \frac{\dot{x}}{x} + \frac{\dot{y}}{y} \big) \dot{z} =0 $$

Can it be solved to get z in terms of a and b ?

**My trial:**

Let $\dot{z}= u = \frac{dz}{dt}$, then $\frac{du}{dt} = \ddot{z}  $. The equation becomes:

$$ \dot{u}+ \big( 3 \frac{\dot{x}}{x} + \frac{\dot{y}}{y} \big) u = 0, $$

separate variables:

$$ \frac{du}{u} = -\big( 3 \frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dt} \big) dt, $$

integrate:

$$ \int \frac{du}{u} = -\big( 3 \int \frac{dx}{x} + \int \frac{dy}{y} \big), $$,

$$ 
log ~u = - \big( 3 log~x + log~y \big) + c, or
$$

$$
u = - y x^3 + c_1,
$$

substitute by u:

$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = - y x^3 + c_1 
$$

**Here** are all the previous steps correct?

Also if I make integration by parts, can a variable like $x^3$ or $y$ be integrated with respect to $dt$? Is it possible to get a final solution in z.

Thanks!

Comment: $z\equiv z(x,y,t)$ or $z \equiv x+yi$?

Comment: What's $a, b$? ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ddot{z} + \big( 3 \frac{\dot{x}}{x} + \frac{\dot{y}}{y} \big) \dot{z} =0$$

$$\dfrac  {\ddot{z}}{\dot z} + 3 \frac{\dot{x}}{x} + \frac{\dot{y}}{y}  =0$$
$$\ln \dot z+3\ln x+\ln y =C$$
$$\dot zx^3y=c_1$$
You can't go further and integrate this DE. You need to knwo what $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are. You need further informations.